# Error 0x80131047 loading MySQL Connector DLL

Tags: mysql, macos, powershell, .net-core, powershell-core

PowerShell has just been opened sourced (v6.0.0-alpha.10), and I'm
trying to get it to connect to a MySQL instance from OS X.

Oracle seems to suggest (if I'm reading it correctly) that they have a
.Net Core connector
[here](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/connector_net_6_8_3).
I ran the install like this:

```
Install-Package MySql.ConnectorNET.Entity -Destination /MySQL
```

and the output looked good:

```
Name                       Version Source Summary                

----                       ------- ------ ------- 
MySql.ConnectorNET.Data    6.8.3.2 nugget ADO.Net driver for MySQL    
MySql.ConnectorNET.Entity  6.8.3.2 nugget MySql Connector/NET for Entity Framework 6
```

When I try loading the assembly like this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load(/MySQL/MySql.ConnectorNET.Data.6.8.3.2/lib/net45/MySql.Data.dll)
```

I get the following error (note that I pass the path in with a
variable `$dll`):

```
Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load
file or assembly
'/MySQL/MySql.ConnectorNET.Entity.6.8.3.2/lib/net40/MySql.Data.dll,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The given assembly name or
codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)" At
/development/scripts/test.ps1:28 char:1
+ [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("$dll")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileLoadException
```

Any ideas on a workaround / fix? I realize that PowerShell is still in
alpha.

**EDIT**

I was able to install the MySQL provider using these two commands:

```
Register-PackageSource -Name nuget.org -ProviderName NuGet -Location https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
Install-Package MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -Destination /Volumes/Main/libraries/MySQL/ -AllowPrereleaseVersions
```

I tried registering all the assemblies I could think of:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll
MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.7.0.5-IR21/lib/netstandard1.6/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
MySql.Data.7.0.5-IR21/lib/netstandard1.6/MySql.Data.dll
```

But, when trying to create a new MySql object, it still bombs out with
this:

> New-Object : Cannot find type [MySql.Data.MySqlClient]:
>   verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

Comment: Apologies if the formatting is a little odd  -I couldn't figure out how to get past the dreaded 'Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted' message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

So, it turns out I was on the (mostly) right track. *All* of the DLLs need to be loaded. Make life easier by copying them into their own directory, and then load them by iterating over each one:

copy the DLLs to a new location

```
Get-ChildItem "/Volumes/Main/libraries/mysql/*/lib/netstandard1.*/*.dll" | Copy-Item -Destination "/Volumes/Main/libraries/NEW_mysql" -Force
```

load all required DLLs

```
Get-ChildItem "/Volumes/Main/libraries/NEW_mysql" | ForEach-Object {
$path = "/Volumes/Main/libraries/NEW_mysql/" + $_.Name
Add-Type -Path $path -PassThru | Out-Null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not a .NET Core library - the word "Core" here indicates functionality shared between the EF6 and Web packages, and pre-dates the introduction of .NET Core.

Entity Framework Core has MySql libraries under development at the time of writing.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Are you aware of any MySql libraries for .Net Core?

Comment: Yes, have a look at https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/mysql/ and https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/pomelo/index.html

Comment: Thanks James. I was able to install the MySQL provider using these two commands: Register-PackageSource -Name nuget.org -ProviderName NuGet -Location https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/  &  Install-Package MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore. However, doing a new-object MySql.Data.MySqlClient isn't proving fruitful. I edited the post with additional information